# Keep previous page state in redux toolkit

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I'm going to implement a product page where it contents similar products when I hit on similar product component it should open same screen component and keep previous product screen in navigation history.

Can anybody help me please?

productSlice.js

```js
const productSlice = createSlice({
  name: "product",
  initialState: {
    product: null,
    loading: false,
  },
  reducers: {
    getProductStart: (state) => {
      state.loading = true;
    },
    getProductSuccess: (state, { payload }) => {
      state.product = payload;
      state.loading = false;
    },
    getProductFailure: (state, { payload }) => {
      state.loading = false;
    },
  },
});

const { actions, reducer } = productSlice;
export const productSelector = (state) => state.product;

export default reducer;

export function fetchProduct(id){
    return dispatch => {
        ...
    }
}
```

store.js

```js
const reducers = combineReducers({
  product: productReducer,
});

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: reducers,
});

export default store;
```

ProductScreen.js

```js
function ProductScreen({ navigation, route }) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { product, loading } = useSelector(productSelector);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchProduct(route.params.id));
  });

  const openSimilarProduct = (id) => {
      navigation.push("ProductScreen", { id });
  }

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{product.name}</Text>
      <Text>{product.description}</Text>

      <View>
          <Pressable onPress={() => openSimilarProduct(1)} >
            <Text>Product #1</Text>
          </Pressable>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

export default ProductScreen;
```

Answer (score 0):

The common pattern in e-commerce appication is fetch product information then fetch similar products and list them in form of grids on bottom.

At high level, you need to fetch product information and by using product metadata like type or category you can fetch  other product with that similar attribute. User don't need to press button for fetch those similar products.